# How can I draw scratch coupons in xamarin forms?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, scratchcard

I want to create scratch coupons for my xamarin.forms app. I want that when user install the app first time, a scratch coupon will visible on top of the app like popup. And then user will scratch it and know what is he getting.

How can we create the scratch coupons in xamarin forms for android and ios?

Comment: take a look at this gestures code https://github.com/twintechs/TwinTechsFormsLib then you can draw with skiasharp following your gestures